# How to prevent more than x number of files from being opened by fs.createReadStream?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, fs, readline

In my code I have a nested `fs.createReadStream(...)` being called within the `readline.on("line"...` event. Initially I had the program failing outright because over 1000 read streams would be created by fs, and the failsafe to stop would trigger.

I implemented a check before opening the read stream to see how many files were open, and if more than I wanted were open I would stall until they were closed. However because the code is called asynchronously it seems over 600 of the checks pass and open files before the other tasks begin stalling. I am having trouble figuring out a way to limit the number of read streams, any solutions would be greatly appreciated.

The purpose of the script overall is to compare two very large files against each other line by line. Each file has well over 200k lines.

I have excluded the functions `formatLine` and `checkLine` as well as refactored my code to try and keep the content relevant to the question.

```js
var fs = require( 'fs' );
const readline = require('readline');

const files = {open: 0};
const wait = ms => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));
//for debugging purposes, just looking at how many files are open
setInterval(() => console.log(files.open), 500);
async function stallIfNeeded() {
  while (files.open > 50) {
    await wait(500);
  }
}
async function checkLineExists(line) {
  await stallIfNeeded();
  let readStream = fs.createReadStream( "./largeFileOfUncertianValues.csv" );
  files.open = files.open + 1;
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: readStream,
    crlfDelay: Infinity
  });
  const hasLine = await new Promise(async res => {
    let found = false;
    rl.on( 'close', () => {
      files.open = files.open - 1;
      res(found);
    });
    rl.on("line", oline => {
      const hasLine = oline.includes(line);
      if (hasLine) {
        found = true;
        rl.close();
      }
    });
  });
  return hasLine;
}

(async () => {
  const sourceStream = fs.createReadStream('largeFileOfKnownValues.csv');

  const sourceRl = readline.createInterface({
    input: sourceStream,
    crlfDelay: Infinity
  });

  let writeStream = fs.createWriteStream("missing.csv")
  let cntr = 0;
  await new Promise(sRes => {
    sourceRl.on("line", async line => {
      //these are conditions left out for simplicity.
      //I need to format every line and check to make sure it is
      //something I want to search for.
      const lineFormatted = formatLine(line);
      const skipLine = checkLine(lineFormatted);
      if (skipLine) return;

      const exists = await checkLineExists(lineFormatted);

      if (!exists) console.log("doesn't exists");
      if (!exists) writeStream.write( line + "\n" );
      if (++cntr % 50 == 0) {
        console.log("another 50 done");
        console.log(cntr + " so far");
      }
    });
    sourceRl.on("close", sRes);
  });
})();
```

Comment: It is very unlikely that this is the right design approach for solving this problem.  You don't want to be reopening the comparison file for every single line in the source file.  Can you describe the problem from scratch in more detail?  Are you just trying to see if two files are identical in content and order?  Or just that the two files contain the same lines, but can be in any order in either file?

Comment: Also, this type of algorithm will benefit from being able to use some memory for caching.  How much memory can you allow the algorithm use?

Comment: Yes, jfriend00. I was thinking maybe I needed to use a database here instead of text files. The two files are basically file paths. However in both locations, the paths can be different yet still valid. i.e. "Hello there" could match "hEllo_there" which is why I have the formatLine function which looks at what the match should be in the other file, and reduces it to something that should pass as `oline.includes(formattedPath)` at the very least. I am doing this on my home pc and I have 16gb of ram, I've never looked into memory cashing though

Comment: the uncertain values also contains more than the known values, I just want to know what is missing.

Comment: You didn't answer my main question.  Do you care about order in the files or are you just looking to see if a path from the source file is contained anywhere in the the target file?  This type of problem is ready made for a database.  Just put all the paths from one file into the database and then for each line in the other file, you just  query the database.

Comment: I do not care about the order in the files. A database is a better solution for the problem, however I am still interested in a way to stall the opening of files.

Comment: @jfriend00 back up-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to minimize memory usage and/or support arbitrarily large files with decent performance, then you really should load one of the files into some sort of database that can do indexed lookup on the data.  Then, you can cycle through one file line by line, normalize the line and then run a query to see if it's present in the other data.

Absent that, here are a couple approaches without a database.  The first one, loads one set of data into an in-memory Set object and then cycles through the second one line by line checking to see what is in the Set (essentially  an in-memory database lookup).

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');

function normalizeLine(line) {
    return line.toLowerCase();
}


async function compare(sourceFile, targetFile) {
    // read in all source lines into a normalized Set
    const source = readline.createInterface({ input: fs.createReadStream(sourceFile) });
    const sourceLines = new Set();
    for await (const line of source) {
        sourceLines.add(normalizeLine(line));
    }

    const notFounds = [];

    const target = readline.createInterface({ input: fs.createReadStream(targetFile) });
    for await (const line of target) {
        if (!sourceLines.has(normalizeLine(line))) {
            notFounds.push(line);
        }
    }
    return notFounds;
}

compare("source.txt", "target.txt").then(result => {
    if (!result.length) {
        console.log("All target lines found in source");
    } else {
        console.log("Not found in source", result);
    }
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

The second one, uses your approach of cycling through the first file line by line, then cycling through  the second file line by line for each line of the first file.  This will be excruciatingly slow for any large data set, but it will scale indefinitely for large files.

This uses the promise interface for readline to cycle through line by line and it `awaits` the close event to avoid any build-up of open files.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');

function normalizeLine(line) {
    return line.toLowerCase();
}

async function compare(sourceFile, targetFile) {
    // read in all source lines into a normalized Set
    const source = readline.createInterface({ input: fs.createReadStream(targetFile) });
    const notFounds = [];
    for await (const line of source) {
        let found = await findLineInFile(sourceFile, line);
        if (!found) {
            notFounds.push(line);
        }
    }
    return notFounds;
}

compare("source.txt", "target.txt").then(result => {
    if (!result.length) {
        console.log("All target lines found in source");
    } else {
        console.log("Not found in source", result);
    }
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});

function streamDestroy(stream) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        stream.once('close', resolve);
        stream.once('error', reject);
        stream.destroy();
    });
}

async function findLineInFile(filename, targetLine) {
    const lookLine = normalizeLine(targetLine);
    const stream = fs.createReadStream(filename);

    const source = readline.createInterface({ input: stream });
    for await (const line of source) {
        if (normalizeLine(line) === lookLine) {
            await streamDestroy(stream);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This is an awesome solution, and I believe I can see how to prevent more files from opening from here, specifically using the `for of` loop in readline, and the streamdestroy function to confirm the stream is closed. Thank you for your time. Do you have any additional input regarding partial matches? For the line by line I can change the conditional easily from `===` to `.includes` however, maybe you have better advice regarding a method similar to [].find for Sets.

Comment: @AsyncAwaitFetch - You'd have to describe in more detail what you're trying to do with partial matches and show examples of what should and shouldn't match.  Sets don't have any partial match functionality so you won't be able to use a Set if that's what you're trying to do.